# How can I pass a CSS class name to a jQuery autocomplete combobox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-autocomplete

jQuery Autocomplete works by putting a select box on the page and doing this:

```
$(".myselect").combobox();
```

where your select box has a class attached to it called "myselect".

The combobox() functionality hides your select box, and puts a text box in its place with all of the jQuery UI classes attached.

What I want to do is bind to events on the box that "replaces" the select box. I *could* attach to one of the jQuery UI classes that are present on that element:

```
<input class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" 
       autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"
       aria-describedby="ui-tooltip-0">
```

However, I don't want to bind to EVERY combobox text box in my whole application. Is there som way to pass a class name to combobox() in order to have it pass that class name on to the text box that it generates?

UPDATE:

No, that's not what I'm asking. I can not figure out how to dynamically add a class to the input box that is being rendered. If I could add a class, then I could use a selector to attach to it. Right now, I sure could still use a selector to attach to it, but it would attach to EVERY input box that was generated by combobox in other parts of my application. I don't want to do that. I only want to bind to the input box on this one page.

How about this. How can I make the combobox example from jQuery AutoComplete put up an alert that says "Hello" after a value has been chosen from the combobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just do an addclass on the text box it generates and add whatever class you want.

```
$("#textboxId").addClass('className');
```

That should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The selection is actually a `<ul>` if you use the CSS selector

```
.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item{

}
```

you should be able to style your auto complete items.